# Does Beaver Woodie get poison damage in Hamlet's Gas Rainforest?

Tags: dont-starve, dont-starve-hamlet

As per the title:

I wonder if [Woodie](https://dontstarve.fandom.com/wiki/Woodie) in beaver form takes damage from Hamlet's [Gas Rainforest biome](https://dontstarve.fandom.com/wiki/Gas_Rainforest)?
So does it progressively lower the beaver meter? And does the rate of damage change?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a chance to try for myself and I can confirm beaver Woodie **does get damage** from the Gas Rainforest, as you can see from the green halo.

Also Woodie was **losing 1 to 2 beaver meter per poison tick**.

[image: Beaver Woodie in Gas Rainforest]